# SignalR - AuthenticationManager.GetTypes() is empty?

Tags: c#, authentication, signalr, owin

Lets say I have a hub:

```
public class MyHub: Hub<IMyHub> {
   public MyHub(){}
   
   public Task DoWork(){
        var principal = this.Context.User; // Currently WindowsIdentity as its not authenticated

        var auth = new OwinContext(this.Context.Request.Environment).Authentication;
        var types = auth.GetAuthenticationTypes(); // Empty list
        // ....
   }
}
```

If I execute same code inside an WebApi2 Controller the `.GetAuthenticationTypes()` would give me the correct result of pre'configured authProviders.

Any ideas why its not behaving like within an controller? Is that by design?

## Update 1

Startup.cs

```
public class Startup 
{
  public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
  {
       var httpConfig = new HttpConfiguration();
       // .. Ioc Registering Hubs
       WebApiConfig.Register(httpConfig);
       FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
       // Have also tried registering signalr here before auth
       // app.MapSignalR("/signalR", new HubConfiguration() { .... }); 
       app.UseOAuthIntrospection(options =>
       {
                //...
                options.AuthenticationType = OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType;
                options.ClientId = clientId;
                options.ClientSecret = clientSecret;
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive;
                options.Events = new OAuthIntrospectionEvents()
                {
                    OnRetrieveToken = context =>
                    {
                        // Getting token from QueryString passed from js app.
                        var token = context.Request.Query["Authorization"];

                        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(token))
                        {
                            context.Token = token;
                        }

                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                 }
                //...
        };
        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.MapSignalR("/signalR", new HubConfiguration() { .... });
        app.UseWebApi(httpConfig); // Have tried swapping these 0 effect
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `Owin` startup part, you should configure `app.MapSignalR();` before registering authentication.

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.MapSignalR();//Configure it first  

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Home/Index")
    });
}
```

Comment: I've added the startup.cs. Have tried to register signalr before the auth but nothing chaged :( can you please take a look?